# Get streak within groupby Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking for a method to calculate the streaks of groups.
For each group, if the previous 'Result' is the same as the current 'Result' then those two results get added together. If the previous 'Result' is different to the current 'Result' or if there is no previous result, then it should return the current result.

Any help is appreciated

```
df_input = pd.DataFrame()
df_input['Name'] = ['A','B','A','A','C','C','B','A','B','C']
df_input['Result'] = [1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1]

df_output = pd.DataFrame()
df_output['Name'] = ['A','B','A','A','C','C','B','A','B','C']
df_output['Result'] = [1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1]
df_output['Streak'] = [1,1,-1,-2,1,2,-1,1,-2,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a group variable first to assign a group to each chunk of consecutive same values in each `Name`:

```
g = df.Result.groupby(df.Name).transform(lambda x: x.diff().ne(0).cumsum())
g
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    1
5    1
6    2
7    3
8    2
9    1
Name: Result, dtype: int32
```

Calculate `cumsum` based on `Name` and the group variable:

```
df['Streak'] = df.Result.groupby([df.Name, g]).cumsum() 
df
  Name  Result  Streak
0    A       1       1
1    B       1       1
2    A      -1      -1
3    A      -1      -2
4    C       1       1
5    C       1       2
6    B      -1      -1
7    A       1       1
8    B      -1      -2
9    C       1       3
```